# Lookup value from DF column in df col names, take value for corresponding row

Tags: r

My DF:

```
dataAB <- c("A","B","A","A","B")
dataCD <- c("C","C","D","D","C")
dataEF <- c("F","E","E","E","F")
key <- c("dataC","dataA","dataC","dataE","dataE")
df <- data.frame(dataAB,dataCD,dataEF,key)
```

I'd like to add a column that looks for the value in "key" in the names of the DF and takes the value in that column for the row. My result would look like this:

```
df$result <- c("C","B","D","E","F")
```

Note that the value in the "key" column only partially matches the col names of df and is not the complete names of the col names. I suspect I'll need `grep` or `grepl` somewhere. I've tried variations on the following code, but can't get anything to work, and I'm unsure how to apply `grep` or `grepl` in this case.

```
df$result <- mapply(function(a) {df[[as.character(a)]]}, a=df$key)
```

Comment: never use `mapply` when you have only 1 function argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `apply` with `margin = 1` (row-wise) from which column we need to take the value using `grepl` which helps to detect the pattern.

```
df$result <- apply(df, 1, function(x) x[grepl(x["key"], names(x))])
df

#  dataAB dataCD dataEF   key result
#1      A      C      F dataC      C
#2      B      C      E dataA      B
#3      A      D      E dataC      D
#4      A      D      E dataE      E
#5      B      C      F dataE      F
```

---

Another option with `mapply` would be to find out the columns from where we need to extract the values using `sapply` and then get the corresponding value from each row.

```
df$result <- mapply(function(x, y) df[x, y], 1:nrow(df), 
            sapply(df$key, function(x) grep(x, names(df), value = TRUE)))

df

#  dataAB dataCD dataEF   key result
#1      A      C      F dataC      C
#2      B      C      E dataA      B
#3      A      D      E dataC      D
#4      A      D      E dataE      E
#5      B      C      F dataE      F
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, with 'tidyverse' :

```
df <- data.frame(dataAB,dataCD,dataEF,key,stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>% mutate(id=row_number())
df %>% gather(k,v,-key,-id) %>% 
 filter(str_detect(substring(k,5),substring(key,5))) %>%
 select(result=v,id) %>% 
 inner_join(df,.,by="id")
#  dataAB dataCD dataEF   key id result
#1      A      C      F dataC  1      C
#2      B      C      E dataA  2      B
#3      A      D      E dataC  3      D
#4      A      D      E dataE  4      E
#5      B      C      F dataE  5      F
```